# How to see code window in gdb if you are using screen utility

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, gnu-screen

I am using screen utility on my linux machine.
I am trying to debug the code using gdb so to display code i am using [ctrl+x ctrl+a]. But nothing is displaying. When I try to do same without screen, I am able to see code window.

Comment: The `Ctrl+a` is eaten by screen (it's a screen meta signalling you will want to do some screen related action, like switching windows, etc)... to send `^a` to the actual window inside screen, do `^a a`  (i.e. Ctrl+a, and "a" without control right after it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `(gdb) layout src`. This is another way to enable TUI mode with source code window besides using key binding [ctrl+x ctrl+a]. See [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Commands.html#TUI-Commands).